# rethinkdb check if record exists

Tags: rethinkdb

Here is an example:

```
r.db('my_db').table('my_table').get('my_record_id_123')
```

The above code works fine, but returns the record. The records in this table are huge. Is there a way to check if the record with that specific id exists or not **without returning the record itself**?

Comment: In ReQL? Or in what language do you want to do this.

Comment: @woodsprite javascript (node.js server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want (it will return true if the record exists or false otherwise):

```
r.db('my_db')
  .table('my_table')
  .getAll('my_record_id_123')
  .count()
  .eq(1)
```

Comment: @Qasim it's in the [manual](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/filter/): `Note: filter does not use secondary indexes. For retrieving documents via secondary indexes, consider getAll, between and eqJoin.`

Comment: Thanks @3k, in my scenario I have a sub-document (a post has many comments, as it's sub-document). I'm not sure if I can add a secondary index to a sub-field?

Answer (score 1):

returns number

```
r.db('my_db')
  .table('my_table')
  .count(function(user){
    return user('id').eq(1121)
  })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
r.db('my_db')
  .table('my_table')
  .getAll('my_record_id_123')
  .contains()
```

This works for me :)