# RethinkDB - Python - Checking if data exists in table

Tags: python, database, rethinkdb

I was wondering If there was a easier way to check if data was in a table. Currently I am having to use

```
users = r.db("main").table("users").filter(r.row['user'] == int(msg.author.id)).run()

for user in blacklist:
    if users['user'] == msg.author.id:
        return # this happens if the user sending a message was found
```

I am having to use this due to the response of users being a rethink Data Cursor

```
<rethinkdb.net.DefaultCursor object at 0x0512C0B0> (done streaming):
```

So it's not like I can use

```
data has item
```

Thank you

Comment: [rethinkdb check if record exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782915/rethinkdb-check-if-record-exists) related?..

Comment: Two things. First of all that is javascript, second of all that is id based not document based in the table data.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, forgot about the list method in python so all I had to do was

data = list(r.db("database").table("table").run())